# A Class named Class?

Tags: object-oriented, coding-style, naming

This is more of a style question, but it is something I am currently pondering for a project of mine.

Assume that you're creating an application which is modeling a school. So there are entities like Student, School, etc. Now this is all fine and intuitive until you get down to Class, as (in most languages) `Class` is a reserved word. So, given that `Class` is a reserved keyword, what would you call such an entity that models a school class?

Comment: SchoolClass????

Comment: You could try a synonym http://thesaurus.com/browse/class

Comment: @MatthewFlynn, that did indeed cross my mind. In fact, it was my first though...

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant to P.SE, this is like the, "Name my band" threads on /b all the time.

Comment: @Malfist _where_ would you see this relevant? I think it is a highly relevant question, as it is universal to software development. Additionally, unlike "name my band", this is no more subjective than "I need a software module for language X to help me parse Excel files".

Comment: @JasonWhitehorn, honestly, not online. If you have to discuss it with someone, your co-workers are ideal. But, "What should I name my class/band/baby" aren't really questions that can be, or should be answered by an online community.

Comment: If this was asked as a generic question about names that conflict with language keywords, it would be universal. But as you phrased the question, its about a specific case of the keyword "class" which is why it not being seen as universal.

Comment: I've been here at a previous job I had. A substitute we used was: 'Syndicate: n. A group with common interest or pursuit'.

Comment: I've reopened the question. Answers that re-iterate other answers or are snarky one-liners will be deleted, same for off topic comments.

Comment: It's a completely legitimate question: "What do you do when your domain-specific term clashes with a term in your chosen programming language". It was just couched in the terms of a specific example, which is fine.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'd pick another term because the word Class can be ambiguous.

Does class refer to:

1. The group of students taking a course?
2. The whole course for this semester?
3. The abstract course taught in multiple semesters?
4. The group of students expected to graduate at a specific time?
5. Some other classification of students, i.e. Advanced Class, Special Needs class.
6. A specific lecture

And that's without even leaving the academic realm. Chances are you can find a better word to fit whatever you are trying to model. Class will only lead to some confusion.

Comment: Ah, yes... very good points. This is the type of discussion I was looking for. I did, in fact, mean "A group of student taking a specific course taught by a specific teacher at a specific time for a single school term (year, semester, etc)"... if that makes any sense. Or, in other words, "I am taking Biology II with Mr. Smith @ 2pm Mondays, Wednesdays, Fridays."

Comment: The general problem of established domain terms clashing with language keywords does remain though...

Comment: In some institutions that's called a Stream. (Which has its own name clash issues :))

Answer (score 21):

You could name it a "Course," or a "Subject," or a "Lecture" if it is a specific class. You could also use "Section," etc.

[Winston Ewert](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/137719/31260) really highlighted the questions you would have to ask yourself.

Comment: +1 for Section. This seems to be what @JasonWhitehorn had in mind, based on his response to Winston Ewert's answer

Answer (score 2):

Finding a synonym is a good idea, e.g "Course."

However, the need to reuse the word class is common (often for a local variable of type *Class*), and the conventional replacements for class  include *klass*, *clazz*,  and *cls*.

Comment: "klass" means you are German (or Dutch), "clazz" is more like "jazz" and "cls", oh, wasn't this used for "CLearScreen" ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends, in some languages `class` is the reserved word, not `Class`.

Comment: I did, however, say "...given that Class is a reserved keyword...", plus, wouldn't you say that two items differing only by case is a horrible idea?

Comment: Doesn't mean you should use it.  Any more than you should use `If`, `Else` or `Goto` in a language where the lower-case versions of these are reserved.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Java already has a `class Class`.

Comment: @JasonWhitehorn: two items differing only by case is not necessarily a bad idea at all – if all your classes have uppercase names while all keywords in your language are lowercase, it's completely unambiguous that `Class` is a custom-defined `class`.

Comment: @Jordan: I couldn't comment (because of the reputation), so I had to post it as an answer.

Comment: Well, now you have the reputation, so you should convert it to a comment, as per the site guidelines and FAQ.

Comment: @Jordan: and how can I convert it?

Comment: You could copy and paste it into a comment to the question, and delete your answer. Not sure it matters anymore, since the question is closed though.

Answer (score 1):

I am agree with @Winston Ewert that I'd pick another term because the word Class can be ambiguous.

In this case you have to use better synonym that suit your implementation. If i do model the such type of architecture then i shall go for **Course**, but there are other synonym also available can be used..

Check a example class architecture that somewhat match to your system. [Ref:](https://knowhow.visual-paradigm.com/uml/association-class/)
[image: Student class and Course class]

As your question tagged with the *naming*, use a noun or noun phrase to name a class from synonym that you use.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from programming language syntax, the word *class* is not a good name from data modeling perspective in the case of a school information system. When you think about what a *class* means you find that (among other things):

A *class* is an regularly scheduled activity that has a start and end and is supervised (taught) by a school educator. Within this activity a subject is taught or an activity (like sport) is performed, so, a subject is offered as zero, one or more *classes*.

So the word *class* is really a "Scheduled Educational Activity" So you have the choic of:

- ScheduledEducationalActivity
- ScheduledActivity (in which case you can be more generic and allow the activity to be educational or an event like a lecture or a seminar or a tournment,...etc.)
- SubjectOffering

So the name *class* really is a convention or (a business name) but is not the best name that describes the entity.

Answer (score 0):

In some programming languages you can use reserved words in the variable names (possibly even class names?). For example in C# you could do like this even though `class` is a reserved word:

```
string @class = "Super class";
```

You could check your programming language specs does it allow you to do this.

If not then just go with Winston Ewerth's answer.

Answer (score -2):

You could declare the entity as ClassRoom!

Comment: That would be a bad name, unless the entity represents the physical room where the class is to be held.